# UITextfield at UISearchbar appears different at simulator and on actual iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar

I managed to customize the look and feel of the UITextfield at UISearchBar using the code below:

> ```
> for (UIView *subview in [searchBar subviews]) 
> {
>         if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarTextField")]){
>             [(UITextField *)subview setBackground:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_searchField.png"]];
>             [(UITextField *)subview setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
>         }
> }
> ```

It appears exactly what I wanted when I use the simulator. However, when I tested it on an actual iPhone, the background image was not visible.

Please advice. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same exact version of iOS on both simulator and device?

Anyway, don't use this black magic, the UISearchFiled is highly customizable through UIAppearance protocol, check "Customizing Appearance" section in [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
Same goes for [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html), you can override text color and background using properties, and do more complicated customization in "Drawing and Positioning Overrides"

Comment: Both simulator and device are currently running on iOS Version 6. I tried using `setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:` but still having the same problem. Simulator and device had different outputs.

Comment: Clearly something is wrong. Try to clean the project, reinstall the app on both platforms. If that doesn't help, maybe you will be able to create a small test project

Comment: Ok, I go clean up and try again. Thank you so much, Dmitry!